# How to restrict date format in date field

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to implement a function that will bring up an alert box when a date in the wrong format is entered and the submit button is pressed. I have six date fields in my form.

I can't seem to find regex examples that show me how to implement the function in my field inputs only how to do the function itself. I wanted to restrict it to YYYY-MM-DD. Posting here is the last resort for me, I have looked for a long time to no avail. Please can someone help?

```
function validate_date() {
    var date_regex = /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\/(19|20)\d{2}$/ ;
    if(!(date_regex.test(testDate)))
    {
    alert('Wrong format!');
    return false;
    }
   }                

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="empexpiry" style="width:350px;" placeholder="Nothing on File" name="empexpiry" value=""
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: What have you tried? Where does your code fail? See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) :o)

Comment: why don't you use a datepicker

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: I've included what i've got so far. I am a beginner as you can see.

Comment: @Anandhunadesh using jQuery for such a simple task is a bit exaggerated

Comment: goto the link...read the description. its not so difficult

Comment: @Werner yeah maybe. y don't you suggest a non-exaggerated solution

Comment: A datepicker is nice and user-friendly, and most of the common ones rely on some external library code. The regex can't validate the date fully, because it can't account for leap years etc. It's actually not a simple task. To do this un-connected to a UI element, moment.js has a simple interface which provides this functionality.  But the missing piece of this is also to validate the date on the server side in PHP as well, which of course is always necessary because client-side code cannot be relied on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the HTML5 pattern attribute was all that was required. Simple!

```
<input id="date" type="text" pattern="\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please make sure the date follows this format: YYYY-MM-DD')" required="required"/>
```

Comment: this won't validate things like leap years, though, or even nonsense like 2017-99-99. And you still need to validate the date server-side in your PHP, because client-side code can easily be bypassed by a knowledgeable and/or malicious user. So it's nice to enhance your GUI's user-friendliness but you can't rely on it to actually verify anything.

Comment: @ADyson I just wanted to ensure the date format was YYYY-MM-DD, I don't mind about any other validation.

Answer (score 0):

If I was you I would use some plugin. There are good vanilla and jQuery plugins to validate forms (e.g. [Vanilla](https://bunnyjs.com/examples/form-validation/), [jQuery](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)).

But if you wanna do it by yourself:

Listen to the submit event of the form and validate all your entries using regex

The function to validate could be something like this

```
function isDateValid (dateStr) {
  let isValid = dateStr.match(/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/)

  if (!isValid) return false

  const dateObj = new Date(dateStr);
  isValid = dateObj != 'Invalid Date'

  return isValid
}
```

And your function to listen the submit could be something like this:

```
function validateForm (e) {

   const input1 = document.getElementById("input1").text

   if (!isDateValid(input1)) {
     alert('invalid')
     e.preventDefault()
     return false
   }

   /* And so on */
}
```